# How to ignore files that don't exist when using IoC with MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control

I am using IoC with my MVC application, and for some reason whenever a file doesn't exist (images mostly), it throws an exception.

Why are images being processed, is this correct?

**Is there a way for it to ignore images somehow or not throw an exception?**

In my global.asax I have this:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new MyControllerFactory ());
```

And then my controller factory looks is:

```
public class MyControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            if (controllerType == null)
            {
                throw new HttpException(404, "Not Found Error");   
            }

            MethodInfo method = Factory.Current.Container.GetType().GetMethods().Where(
                m => m.Name == "Resolve" && m.IsGenericMethod).First(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 0);

            return (IController)method.MakeGenericMethod(controllerType).Invoke(Factory.Current.Container, null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not so clear what you really mean by "images are being processed". Where are they processed? What moment are they processed?

Comment: What I mean is, a .jpg file is coming through the asp.net process.  I thought since it is a static file it shouldn't go through the process but be handled like a static file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IoC Castle Windsor in MVC routing problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678635/ioc-castle-windsor-in-mvc-routing-problem)